# Parse query parameters with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse the url `/domain.com?filter[a.b.c]=value1&filter[a.b.d]=value2`
and get 2 groups: '**a.b.c**' and '**a.b.d**'.

I try to parse with regexp `[\?&]filter\[(.+\..+)+\]=` but the result is '**a.b.c]=value1&filter[a.b.d**'. How can I specify to search for the 1st occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/[?&]filter\[([^\].]+\.[^\]]+)]=/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ig0G6u/1)

**Details**

- `[?&]`  - a `?` or `&`
- `filter\[` - a `filter[` substring
- `([^\].]+\.[^\]]+)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^\].]+` - 1 or more chars other than `]` and `.`
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^\]]+` - 1 or more chars other than `]`
- `]=` - a `]=` substring

JS demo:

```js
var s = '/domain.com?filter[a.b.c]=value1&filter[a.b.d]=value2';
var rx = /[?&]filter\[([^\].]+\.[^\]]+)]=/g;
var m, res=[];
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Note that in case `&` is never present as part of the query param value, you may add it to the negated character classes, `[^\].]+` => `[^\]&.]+`, to make sure the regex does not overmatch across param values.

Since you need to extract text inside outer square brackets that may contain consecutive `[...]` substrings with at least 1 dot inside one of them, you may use a simpler regex with a bit more code:

```js
var strs = ['/domain.com?filter[a.b.c]=value1&filter[a.b.d]=value2', 
'/domain.com?filter[a.b.c]=value1&filter[a.b.d]=value2&filter[a][b.e]=value3', 
'/domain.com?filter[a.b.c]=value1&filter[b][a.b.d][d]=value2&filter[a][b.e]=value3'];
var rx = /[?&]filter((?:\[[^\][]*])+)=/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  var m, res=[];
  console.log(s);
  while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
    if (m[1].indexOf('.') > -1) {
      res.push(m[1].substring(1,m[1].length-1));
    }
  }
  console.log(res);
  console.log("--- NEXT STRING ----");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can I make expression more complicate? `/domain.com?filter[a.b.c]=value1&filter[a.b.d]=value2&filter[a][b.e]=value3`
We should to get 3 groups: 'a.b.c', 'a.b.d' and 'a][b.e' (or 'b.e.')

Comment: @Alexander It will be a bit too complex with a single regex. You may do it with a bit simpler regex and a bit of code.

Comment: I written so: `[?&]filter\[([^=.]+\.[^\]]+)]=`
Is it have any problems?

Comment: @Alexander The problem is that you may overflow across square brackets as `[^=.]+` matches any 1+ chars other than `=` and `.` (i.e. it matches `[` and `]`, and may match a part of one value and then the whole substring till the matching ending part).

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[\?&]filter\[)([^\]]+\.[^\]]+)+(?!>\]=)
```

This will give you only the groups you mentioned (`a.b.c` and `a.b.d`)

This part `(?<=[\?&]filter\[)` says recognise but don't capture `[?&]filter` before what you want and this part `(?!>\]=)` says recognise but don't capture after `]` after what you want.

`[^\]]` this captures everything that isn't a square bracket